# Always getting NULL on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to populate the second dropdown depending on the value of first drop down value. For this, when I click on First Dropdown I am trying to connect to my "s_Test3_AjaxIndex.jsp" page to fetch the results for second drop down. But, I am always getting the value of **str** as *null* and then the code terminates because of *return* statement. Can someone help me out that where I am doing wrong, so that I can get the correct value of my option tag. Here, the connection to the required jsp is now the secondary part, I am not even getting the value of str here. Please help.

Below is my test.jsp page:
NOTE: The Script is in the head tag

```js
function sendInfo()  
{  
 var str=document.ajaxform.class_class.value;  
 var xmlhttp;
 if (str=="")
 {
   document.getElementById("sectionlist").innerHTML="null";
   return;
 }
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
     document.getElementById("sectionlist").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","s_Test3_AjaxIndex.jsp?val="+v,true);
 xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form name="ajaxform" action="#">
 <select name="class_class" onmouseup="sendInfo()">
     <option value='' disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Class</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">4</option>
           <option value="5">5</option>
 </select>
 
 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <p>Select Section</p>
 <div id="sectionlist">Select Class to get Sections</div>
 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of only doing something if `xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200` I would alert the return in any case so you know, whats coming back from the server for debugging

Comment: @TomDoodler yes sure, I will keep in mind, but could you please let me know that why I am getting the value of str null here :var str=document.ajaxform.class_class.value;

Comment: ok that was a missunderstanding, I didnt get the problem ^^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","s_Test3_AjaxIndex.jsp?val="+v,true);
```

to:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","s_Test3_AjaxIndex.jsp?val="+str,true);
```

as "v" variable is not defined.

Comment: I think variable 'v' has been defined outside the piece of code he posted.

Comment: sorry that was typo.. my mistake. I replaced v with str and it works fine now. Thanks Haris and Joost

Answer (score 1):

Change from `onmouseup` to `onchange`. Not sure why, but it seems to work.

Comment: Because the onChange gets called when the new select value is set, and onmouseup slightly before the value is available.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding event onMouseUp that is not required here ,you should use instead

```
<select name="class_class" onchange="sendInfo()">
```